# How to use Lettuce for REST API testing?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, lettuce

I have been learning for a couple of hours how to test python code with Lettuce. I would also like to test Django applications for REST requests and responses with URLs. Can I achieve this with Lettuce?

Lettuce home page: [lettuce.it](http://lettuce.it)

Comment: just my very own opinon: for BDD have you tried [behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/index.html) instead of lettuce?

Comment: Yes you can, that is what Lettuce is for. As mentioned, also read about Behave too, and then judge what would work for you. You should post a question to SO when you encounter difficulties with your BDD tests. Right now get your hands dirty.

Answer (score -1):

I think yes. There's a special lettuce app for django. Here's a nice intro how to test Django REST API with lettuce - http://lettuce.it/recipes/django-lxml.html